# Wait a maximum of N seconds for something to happen

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

In my JS code I needed to wait up to 3 seconds for a flag to be true. I did the following:

```
const waitForSomethingToBeTrue = (something) => {
    const maxWaitingTime = 3 * 1000;

    let promises = [];
    for (let i = 100; i < maxWaitingTime; i += 100) {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (something()) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject(something.name + " didn't happen in " + i + "miliseconds.");
                }
            }, i);
        }));
    }

    return Promise.any(promises).catch(() => {
        return Promise.reject(`${something.name} didn't happen in maximum allowed
            time (${maxWaitingTime} msecs).`);
    });
};
```

As you can notice, there are a couple of problems with my approach:

1. I'm creating many unnecessary timeouts, for example, if promise at the 200msec mark is resolved, rest of them is unneeded and will already resolve
2. I'm using Promise.any, which is not officially supported yet. I solved this by writing a shim, using Promise.all reversed, but still, an officially supported method would be better.

how can I solve this problem without having the above issues?

Comment: Maybe a single `setInterval`, keep track of how long it's been, and if it's been too long then clear the interval and reject the promise. Just don't forget to also clear the interval on success to stop the polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with just a single promise, which either `resolve` if `something` is true or `reject` if it gets to the time

```js
const waitForSomethingToBeTrue = (something) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    const intervalId = setInterval( () => {
      if(something()){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        resolve();
      }
      else{
        timer = (new Date().getTime() - start);
        if( timer > 3000){
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          reject("took too long");
        }
      }
    },100);
  });
}

// test code below just sets a global bool to true by clicking the button
var globalBool = false;
async function testIt(){
  document.querySelector("#clickme").addEventListener("click",() => globalBool = true);
  
  try{
    await waitForSomethingToBeTrue(() => globalBool);
    console.log("It was true");
   }
   catch(error){
    console.log(error);
   }
}

testIt();
```

```html
<button id="clickme">Click me to make something true</button>
```

Comment: All answers are good, thanks everybody. I'm going to mark this one since it went to the trouble of writing a test.

Comment: The timer on this is not accurate since setTimeout/Interval creeps overtime. Small times, not a big deal, larger time frames bigger deal.

Comment: @epascarello totally. This was a huge shortcut and I should have done it better. Updating now.

Answer (score 2):

Make one promise, make a check inside that keeps checking the state.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
  return x === 10;
}



function waitFor(method, max) {

  var start = Date.now();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    function check() {
      var result = method();
      if (result) {
        resolve();
      } else if (Date.now() - start > max) {
        reject();
      } else {
        window.setTimeout(check, 100);
      }
    }
    
    check();

  });


}

waitFor(myFunction, 3000)
  .then(() => console.log('good'))
  .catch(() => console.log('bad'));
```

Comment: Your solution is very useful. I have a question: how do I pass parameters if myFunction takes one?

Comment: `waitFor(myFunction.bind(this, value1, value2), 1000)` or `waitFor(function () {myFunction(value1, value2)}), 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a single setInterval, and clear it and resolve/reject a single promise:

```js
const gen = function(t) {
    let value = false;
    setTimeout(() => value = true, t);
    return () => value;
};

const success = gen(2500);
const err = gen(3500);

const watch = (value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (value()) {
                resolve(true);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(interval);
            reject('did not complete in time');
        }, 3000)
    });
}

watch(success).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
watch(err).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that uses `async` `await` in combination with a promisified `setTimeout` (called `delay`):

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const waitForSomethingToBeTrue = async (something, giveUp) => {
    let expired = () => true;
    delay(giveUp).then(() => something = expired);
    while (!something()) await delay(100);
    if (something === expired) throw "expired";
    return "success";
};

// Test whether button is pressed in time
buttonClicked = false;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => buttonClicked = true);

waitForSomethingToBeTrue(() => buttonClicked, 5000)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);
```

```html
<button>Make something true</button><br>
Press the button with 5 seconds to get success. If that delay expires this is reported.
```